# mysql show all other results from company

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have a question. This is my database structure

```
**company**
id | name
---------
1, Test
2, demo

**address**
id | name
---------
1, test1
2, test2
3, bla6

**address_company**
id | address_id | company_id
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
3, 3, 2
```

My query is this:

```
SELECT company.name, address.name FROM company 
INNER JOIN address_company on address_company.company_id = company.id
INNER JOIN address on address.id = address_company.address_id
```

This works. But I need to filter results.

So when people click address (frontend): test1, it only needs to show company: Test

I can do this:

```
WHERE address.name = "test1"
```

This also works but I need to filter further so what I need is

```
WHERE address.name = "test1" AND address.name = "test2"
```

But this doesn't work, it doesn't show results. I can only filter on 1 address and I need to filter on more addresses.

Hope you guys can understand me and can help me.
THANKS!

Comment: I want to filter on the addresses so it shows companies where address is 'test1' and 'test2'. Btw this is some example and not my real code, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below strategy leans on the `unique key(address_id,company_id)` making sure there are no duplicates at that combo-level

### Schema

```
create table company
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);
insert company(name) values ('Test'),('demo');

create table address
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);
insert address(name) values ('test1'),('test2'),('bla6');

create table address_company
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    address_id int not null,
    company_id int not null,
    unique key(address_id,company_id) -- no dupes allowed ! I am banking on this below
);
insert address_company(address_id,company_id) values (1,1),(2,1),(3,2);
```

### The queries

```
select company_id,count(*) theCount from address_company 
where address_id in (1,2) 
group by company_id having theCount>1;

+------------+----------+
| company_id | theCount |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        2 |
+------------+----------+

select company_id,count(*) theCount from address_company 
where address_id in (select id from address where name in ('test1','test2'))
group by company_id having theCount>1;

+------------+----------+
| company_id | theCount |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        2 |
+------------+----------+
```

So if the group by / having returns greater than 1 for the count, where I literally went after name1 and name2, then I know that row qualifies. And that row of course then has name1 *and* name2.

Back to the unique key part: This assures we aren't tricked in having a company with the same address twice. Which first off doesn't make sense, and also that would mess up this strategy.

Obviously the schema needs some index help, and FK's wouldn't break anyone's heart. But this is just a strawman.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Because I also use full text search I cant use FK's :(

Answer (score 1):

Use OR instead of and, or use the in() structure:

```
WHERE address.name = 'test1' OR address.name = 'test2'


WHERE address.name IN('test1', 'test2' )
```

Note: I hope that the below join condition was just typed incorrectly in the question:

```
 INNER JOIN address on address.id = address_company.id
```

Comment: The join is incorrect but I changed it :) It's just an example.
But I want to filter on the results, so I want to is shows all companies where address.name = 'test1' and then I want to filter more, so it will show all companies with address.name = 'test1' and 'test2' and your code will show all companies where address.name = 'test1' or 'test2'. Thats not what I want